# HTMLTableColor to set table cell color conditionlly

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have been using this for HTML Color coding using PowerShell,
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-HTML-Notificatio-e1c5759d/view/Discussions#content

Can you help in comparing the values within the table itself rather then argument value in Add-HTMLTableColor

For Ex, I need to compare Usage with Budget and color code Usage accordingly.

### Name | Budget | Usage

### ABC  | 1000   | 900

XYZ  | 500    | 510

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Be Default Add-HTMLTableColor allows argument to be passed for comparison and sets the cell color based on the results, I wanted to compare within the table column values and color code.